# Why should I collectstatic in django?

Tags: django, collectstatic

What is the necessity to do collectstatic in django? Why can't I just copy files to the static folder and make my server refer to that folder? Why does that not work?

Comment: Any django app that is installed in `settings.py` and follows the `django.contrib.static` folder convention will have its static files installed into the directory that you choose. This includes 3rd party apps so you don't have to go scrounging around in your `site-packages` just to get some static files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convenience?  You can manually copy over the static files and there's no problem with doing that, but when you have multiple different folders where static files are stored and you're deploying to a production server, it's much more of a hassle to go individually to each folder and copy them instead of having `collectstatic` run as an automated task and do the work for you.

Comment: I feel still that the question is unanswered. What do we mean by go 'individually to each folder' ? If that's where the static files found let them be there and it's the packages responsibility to refer the proper path. Why would I soil the static folder? Let them be served from `site-packages` itself